# Why is my program crashing when at least 1 of 4 list becomes empty?

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating the card game 'war' in python. In war you divide up all 52 cards to the players. The problem that I am having is when one suit list becomes empty, it crashes the program. I have tried to solve it by saying that `suit = random.choice(poss_suits)`, after `except IndexError:`, but that didn't work. Any ideas?

```
Diamonds = ['Ace', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
Hearts = ['Ace', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
Spades = ['Ace', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
Clubs = ['Ace', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']

poss_suits = [Diamonds, Hearts, Spades, Clubs]
```

```
player_deal = 52
while player_deal > 0:
    try:
        suit = random.choice(poss_suits)

        if suit == Diamonds:
            card = random.choice(Diamonds)
            Diamonds.remove(card)

        if suit == Hearts:
            card = random.choice(Hearts)
            Hearts.remove(card)

        if suit == Spades:
            card = random.choice(Spades)
            Spades.remove(card)

        if suit == Clubs:
            card = random.choice(Clubs)
            Clubs.remove(card)

        Player.hand.append(card)
        player_deal -= 1
    except IndexError:
```

Comment: Just thoughts: I would implement the pack to  match how you do it physically. 1) Make a deck of four suits. 2) shuffle it. 3) treat it as a stack and pop from the top.  Easy to understand, easy to code and test. It can be used anywhere a deck of cards is required. Note: a card is a record of [Suit, value].

Answer (score 1):

Doing `list.remove(card)` gives a ValueError if `list` is empty. You dealt with the IndexError but not the ValueError.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add:

```
if suit == Diamonds and Diamonds:
```

Then, do the same for the other suits. Another better way is if you use suit as follows:

```
player_deal = 52
while player_deal > 0:
    try:
        suit = random.choice(poss_suits)
        if suit:
            card = random.choice(suit)
            suit.remove(card)
            Player.hand.append(card)
            player_deal -= 1
```

This is a more simplified answer that does the job.